# How to return a value from a Python callback in Fortran using F2Py

Tags: callback, fortran, intel-fortran, f2py

Consider the following Fortran subroutine, defined in test.f:

```
subroutine test(py_func)

use iso_fortran_env, only stdout => output_unit

external py_func

integer :: a
integer :: b

a = 12
write(stdout, *) a

b = py_func(a)
write(stdout, *) b

end subroutine
```

Also the following Python code, defined in call_test.py:

```
import test

def func(x):
    return x * 2

test.test(func)
```

Compiled with the following (Intel compiler):

```
python f2py.py -c test.f --fcompiler=intelvem -m test
```

I expect this as output when I run test:

```
      12
      24
```

But I actually get this:

```
      12
       0
```

It seems as if `b` is being initialised with a default value instead of the result of `test`.  I have tried using the following in the Fortran:

```
!f2py intent(callback) py_func
      external py_func
!f2py integer y,x
!f2py y = py_func(x)
```

But my program crashes after the printout of `12` to the console.

Any ideas what could be going on here?  The reason for the crash would be a bonus, but I'm really just interested in getting a simple callback working at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't claim to understand it, I found the answer on an [F2Py forum thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.f2py.user/1810). Adding `integer py_func` (*not* prefixed by `!f2py`) does the trick for me:

```
subroutine test(py_func)

use iso_fortran_env, only stdout => output_unit

!f2py intent(callback) py_func
external py_func
integer py_func
!f2py integer y,x
!f2py y = py_func(x)

integer :: a
integer :: b

a = 12
write(stdout, *) a

b = py_func(a)
write(stdout, *) b

end subroutine
```

Perhaps this is to do with space being needed for a temporary value used to store the result before being assigned to b?  In any case, it is apparently compiler-dependent, which explains why it is not in various F2Py callback examples you can find elsewhere online.

Comment: You do not have `implicit none` in your file, therefore `py_func` is considered `real` due to the implicit typing rules.